# Using php eval on code from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, eval

I am attempting to auto-generate a form based on information in a Mysql database.  Right now, one table stores information about the fields that are needed - the field type, maxlength, default value, etc.

A second table contains html / php code for displaying the proper form input, based on information retrieved from the previously mentioned table. Neither of these tables include any user-inputed data. In order to process and display this stored code, I have been trying to use php's eval function. Although I'm not sure this is a good solution, the only alternative I could think of was to have dozens of one or two line files which are retrieved by using php's include or using jquery to append the contents. The main reason I didn't want to do this was to avoid having the dozens of extra files.

Here is the eval statement that I have so far

```
eval("\$code=\"$field[input_code]\";");echo"<td>$code</td>";
```

Here is a sample of one of the contents of $field['input_code']

```
<input name='".$field['form_name']."'type='text'placeholder='".ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$field['form_name']))."'".if($field['req']==1){echo"class='textvalreq'required";}else{echo"class='textval'";}.">
```

Comment: "I have a Mysql database which stores code for displaying form inputs." --- **DON'T DO THAT**

Comment: oh the humanity. There needs to be a close option "idea to insane to contemplate"

Comment: This code is used to auto-generate forms based on the type of input needed.  A Mysql database contains the list of fields needed, along with the type of field, name, maxlength, etc.  Then, based on that information, the form is automatically generated using aforementioned code pieces.

Comment: your explanation makes this no less wrong.

Comment: One of these has to be related http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+eval+database

Comment: Any alternative would be appreciated

Comment: @Dagon - I understand that the eval function may not be a good way to solve this problem. I couldn't think of a better alternative, other than creating dozens of additional files each containing only a line or two of code.  In the end, that may be a better solution, but being relatively inexperienced I thought that I would pose the question here to get some feedback. The purpose of this forum is to educate and assist - not to berate and belittle. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be here!

Comment: then you should be asking the question "how do i do ..." instead of "how do i use eval",  which i know is wrong. its an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Apart from eval or not - store the field type in the database - that is okay. However the code belongs into PHP. The database contains the configuration data only. Then the PHP generates the form and all is fine. You can then easily extend the forms with new features without editing many fields in the database.

Comment: Appreciated @hakre. That's the route that I'm going. I was thinking that it would be easier to have everything in the database...but I'm finding that it's more trouble than it's worth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$field['input_code']` contains an expression,

```
eval("\$code=\"$field[input_code]\";");
```

will not work as php would try to do sth. like:

```
$code = "if (<condition>) { ... }";
```

This would eventually end up as a valid string but if the variable contains quotes all hell will break loose.

I'm sorry. I don't see a trivial solution to the problem other than not storing arbitrary code in a database and trying to `eval()` it.

Btw: `eval()` is evil.

Comment: I understand the issues with eval, but I don't know of another way to accomplish this.  Any alternative suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: don't do it, but here is how? do you need the reputation points so badly?

Comment: alternative? put the code in a file? how is that difficult?

Comment: @Dagon The best way to educate about security issues is to show how it works and where the issue is. I could even go into more detail but i'll leave that to you ;)

Comment: @glasz - I appreciate you trying to help explain why it won't work well instead of just judging!

Comment: @Alan another approach was just coming to my mind: use [a template engine](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.eval.tpl). this, at least to some extend, allows you to securely work with arbitrary input.